# Android MMS application

Tags: android, newline, mms, enter

I want to modify the default MMs application in Android so that the enter key don't cause the message to be sent.

In other words, I want when the user enters "Enter key", the application insert new line instead of sending the message.

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this unless you have access to the full ASOP source code and can recompile the MMS application. And this would require that you modify the MMS Application source code and then replace the APK on a device. Specifically unless you have your own device/rom this is not going to be possible from **ONLY** an application's perspective. You must have access to the platform.

Comment: In this case, we won't architect your solution, but you need to find out where OnKeyListener code is inside of the MMS Application and then implement it from there. Learn to navigate the code.